# Create a PHP array from an array from of HTML input values in a for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, forms

I've trying to create an array that consists of the values of inputs in loops. I am very new to PHP and looked up several other questions but to no avail. I am taking a random number "$QuestionNoSelect" and selecting a text and info from a MySQL server about the question.

```
//For loop for displaying and naming
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++)
{

$QuestionNoSelect = rand(1,16);

array_push($IDListing, $QuestionNoSelect);

$sql = "SELECT QuestionText FROM johnconn_sstest.tbRandomArray WHERE QuestionNo = $QuestionNoSelect";
$QuestionText = $conn->query($sql);

if ($QuestionText->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $QuestionText->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

        //Number Question, Increment, Question then input box
        echo "<br><br>".$QuestionNumberer. ". ". "<br>";
        echo "Question number ID= ".$QuestionNoSelect, "<br>";

        $QuestionNumberer++;
        echo $row["QuestionText"];
        echo '<br>'.'Answer';
        echo "<input type='text' name='answerbox[]'  id='answerbox[]' class='userInfo' value='".$i."'/>";
        echo '<br>'.'comment(if Applicable)';
        echo "<input type='text' name='commentbox[]' id='commentbox'[]' class='userInfo' value='".$i."'/>";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

}

I am trying to get these values from the array of names or IDs I've created but cannot figure out why I can't get it to work. I cannot even get the array of values to print

```
//PRINT ANSWER 
echo '<br>Answer List <br>';

 for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++)
 {
 $_POST("answerbox[$i]");
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are typos in your script look for `commentbox'[]' class='use` (one `'` to mutch) and just do `foreach($_POST['answerbox'] as $value){ print $answer; }`  To understand it better do an `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I recommend not running 10 separate queries.  Get your 10 random question numbers, and ask your database for them -- only once.  Why are you putting `$i` into the answerbox and commentbox field values?  There is a lot that doesn't make sense to me about your code.  Shouldn't you being using `$i` as your `Numberererer`?

Comment: I put $i into the var box to check if it worked. The text input boxes have a default value of whatever I put in the field values. 

Yeah I'm confused on how that works. I had the $i inside the square brackets before but I had the same problems. I looked up other SO questions similar to this and they didn't have the $i inside the square brackets. This is the first ever program I've made using HTML and PHP. I'm sure it's awfully written.

Comment: do you have any <form> tags in your code?  How is this submitted?

Comment: I currently have a the whole for loop inside a form with a submit button at the end. Though when I press submit, the questions that were selected are rescrambled. I could probably fix that quite easily though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you are treating $_POST like it is a function (`$_POST()`) instead of an array (`$_POST[]`).  Because your form fields are 1-dimensional arrays, your $_POST data is a 2-dimensional array.  Access the submitted array elements using this syntax:

```
$_POST[formfieldname][numerickey]
```

I have rewritten a portion of your code and added some refinements which should improve efficiency and show some good practices.

```
$conn=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
$conn->select_db('johnconn_sstest');  // designate a default database
$sql="SELECT QuestionNo,QuestionText FROM tbRandomArray ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;";  // until your table gets very, very large RAND() will serve you well
if($result=$conn->query($sql)){  // declare $result and check if true/success or false/syntax failed
    $i=0;
    echo "<form action=\"receiving_page.php\" method=\"post\">";  // assign receiving page and data delivery method
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){  // loop through your db table rows
            ++$i;
            echo "Q$i ID:{$row['QuestionNo']}<br>";  // show counter and question's row id
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"QNo[$i]\" value=\"{$row['QuestionNo']}\">";  // invisibly pass question id to receiving page
            echo "{$row['QuestionText']}<br>";
            echo "Answer <input type=\"text\" name=\"answerbox[$i]\"  id=\"answerbox$i\" class=\"userInfo\" value=\"\"><br>";  // assign numeric key to each answer input name beginning with 1
            echo "Comment(if Applicable) <input type=\"text\" name=\"commentbox[$i]\" id=\"commentbox$i\" class=\"userInfo\" value=\"\"><br><br>";  // assign numeric key to each answer input name beginning with 1
        }
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";  // submit button with no name attribute so the value is not passed to the receiving page
    echo "</form>";
}else{
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

@ receiving_page.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["QNo"]) && sizeof($_POST["QNo"])==10  && 
   isset($_POST["answerbox"]) && sizeof($_POST["answerbox"])==10  && 
   isset($_POST["commentbox"]) && sizeof($_POST["commentbox"])==10){
    foreach($_POST["QNo"] as $index=>$value){
        // do whatever you like with the values, use $index access other arrays' elements
        // $value is each QNo in sequence.
        // $_POST["answerbox"][$i] is answerbox value in the same QNo row
        // $_POST["commentbox"][$i] is commentbox value in the same QNo row
    }
}else{
    echo "Did not receive the full batch of expected values";
}
```

Of course, on your form, the fields' keys (`$i` in `fieldname[$i]`) can be omitted like this: `fieldname[]` -- this may be preferable but just be aware that then the numerickeys will start at 0 instead of 1 and will automatically increment.

Comment: What are your suggestions?

Comment: What I mean is, it might be helpful to describe how you've solved the problem so that other readers can benefit from it, too. It's hard to tell what the problem was just by looking at the code you've rewritten.

Comment: I'll quote what it says.

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

I'm not trying to scum you out of an upvote my friend haha.

Answer (score -1):

print_r is your friend.  You can print_r($_POST) which will let you see if you have what you think you have.  Once you see that it should be clear why you aren't seeing what you want.

If this code is intended to be printing the answers, it needs to be something like

```
echo $_POST["answerbox[{$i}]"];
```

Comment: I agree with @justOnUnderMillions but can't comment there.  I thought of a foreach, but given his unfamiliarity with php and the need for it be in a specified order, I didn't suggest that change

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed the typo and have been trying to get anything to print from the array but can't seem to.

    foreach($_POST['answerbox'] as $value)
    { 
        echo $_POST["answerbox[$i]"];
 print_r($_POST["answerbox[$i]"]);
 echo $_POST($value[$i]);
 print_r($_POST($value[$i]));}

Comment: just start with print_r($_POST) - also put something in the loop to see if you are iterating at all.  If you post the _POST we could probably help more

Comment: I've tried 4 different variations of print there. I'm sure I'm doing something foolish but I'm out of ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Oh and you probably would want $_POST["answerbox[{$i}]"];

Comment: Another cool thing about print_r is if you want it to return a string (for example you are using it in a debug log or as part of a form, you can use print_r(_POST, true);  (add , true to the call)

Comment: I think there's a problem with the answerbox itself because nothing at all will print in "foreach($_POST['answerbox'] as $value){}"  Not even simple echoed strings.

Comment: that means $_POST['answerbox'] is not an array.  What did print_r($_POST); give us?

Comment: It won't print inside the for loop but outside of the for loop it prints "Array ()"

Comment: That means you don't have the post variable from the html - there are several questions on SO dealing with that problem

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is correct syntax because the OP asking where the variable inside post was answerbox[0], answerbox[1] etc.  answerbox was not a variable but $i was?

Comment: I assume the downvote is because your syntax doesn't return the expected result. Your code references an index of the `$_POST` array called "answerbox[1]". But the OP's HTML code would generate an array with index "answerbox" whose value is another array of values. See [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dc6f5b7274570033ef7af868c0c38aad8b1b538).

Comment: Ok - I buy that - Thanks!